# Is there are way to manually create a base64code from an image in JS

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I draw an image in html canvas.

This is how you calculate the pixels

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 4) {

          var red = data[i]; // red
          var green= data[i + 1]; // green
          var blue = data[i + 2] ; // blue
             }
```

and this is how you create the base64 code out of it

```
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
```

But this creates base64 code for a png image with RGBa. What do I do to create the base64 code from only the first channel `data[i]` is there a way to manually encode it to base64 or give the toDataURL options to do so? I tried looking up the documentation but I couldn't find anything

Thanks

**EDIT**

edit with markE suggestion:

```
    var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0,0,cw, ch);
     var data= imageData.data        
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 4) {
          var grayscale = data[i]*0.2126 + data[i +1]*0.7152 + data[i +2]*0.0722;
          data[i]     = grayscale; // red
          data[i + 1] = grayscale; // green
          data[i + 2] = grayscale; // blue
             }


var binary = new Uint8Array(data.length);
for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
  binary[i]=data[i];
}
var s=binary.toString();
 var base = btoa(s);
```

Comment: you can set the data to say, convert to B+W, but the canvas output options will all be RGB(sometimes A). you can use `("image/jpeg", 0.5)` to get just RGB, relatively compact

Comment: Is there any other way how I can do that? the reason I am asking is, because I have a grayscaled image so to pass an image around I don't need the other channels.

Comment: You could (1) Save your remaining grayscale values to a `Uint8Array`, (2) Stringify that array with `var s=myUint8Array.toString()`, (3) Base64 encode that string with `btoa(s)`. My question is what are you going to use that result for?

Comment: Ok, I added the suggestion you made, thank you ! I think I am a lot closer now. But why is the binary array empty?

Comment: I mean the outcome is [object Uint8Array]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could:

1. Save your remaining grayscale values to a `Uint8Array`,
2. Stringify that array with `var s=myUint8Array.toString()`,
3. Base64 encode that string with `btoa(s)`.

**Here's example code:**

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

var img=new Image();
img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
img.onload=function(){
  canvas.width=img.width;
  canvas.height=img.height;
  ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
  var uint8 = new Uint8ClampedArray(img.width*img.height);
  var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
  var data= imageData.data        
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 4) {
    var grayscale = data[i]*0.2126 + data[i +1]*0.7152 + data[i +2]*0.0722;
    uint8[i]=grayscale;
  }
var s=uint8[0];
for(var i=1;i<uint8.length;i++){
    s+=','+uint8[i];
}
  alert('As string: '+s);
  var b64=btoa(s);
  alert('As base64 string'+b64);
  var ss=atob(b64);
  alert('Back to original string'+ss);
}
img.src='https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/house16x16.jpg'
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; margin:0 auto; }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, however, if I run your code, the b64 will be an empty object again

Comment: It works fine for me...I'm getting a valid Base64 encoding in Chrome, Firefox, Edge. Are you running my demo above or are you using your own image? Are you getting a cross-domain security violation?

Comment: I am using your code snippet and I get "W29iamVjdCBVaW50OEFycmF5XQ==" as an alert

Comment: and no cross-domain security violation

Comment: Your alert result looks like success to me -- a Base64 encoded string.

Comment: yeah but when you decode it it says "[object Uint8Array]" which means there is no actual value in the array. Thanks btw, that was exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Chuckle, I'm not really sure what happened here! Did I answer your question? :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88277/discussion-between-paul-bernhard-wagner-and-marke).

Comment: any idea why the value is 0 there?

Comment: the to string method doesn't work, it doesn't convert binary data

Comment: @PaulBernhardWagner. Ouch, you're right, `Uint8Array.toString` basically returns the datatype of the array, not its contents. **Sorry about that!** I've edited my answer to manually convert the array to a CSV string.

Comment: where did you find this? I was thinking of importing this file here https://github.com/beatgammit/base64-js

Comment: Where...hmmm? I use & understand atob, btoa & .getImageData. Given that understanding I just put the pieces together. So I guess this is just a case of putting the building blocks together in the proper order(?). :-)

Comment: and why did you use a `ClampedArray`? isn't `data` itself a `ClampedArray` so I could use `data` instead of starting a new array?

Comment: A clamped array restricts the range of values that it can contain. Uint8ClampedArray restricts all of its values to being integers between 0 & 255. If you assign a value outside that range, javascript will automatically convert it to the closest in-range value. And yep, `.getImageData(x,y,w,y).data` is actually a Uint8ClampedArray. You could use the data array -- keep in mind the r,g,b values are all identical & would take up more space than creating a new array. I guess the choice depends on what you want to use the b64 string for.